# I need a for loop made by filled in information, the birthplace shown as much as the years of the age

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I have made a form with Birthplace (`$plaats`) and age (`$leeftijd`). and i need to show "Eindhoven the craziest" if the person  lives in Eindhoven and older than 18.

But i have to echo this sentence as much as the years of the age, by example if the age is 19, i have to echo "eindhoven the craziest"  19 times. 
I have made it to this but i cant get any further:

```
if ($leeftijd >=18 && $plaats == "Eindhoven")
{ 

}
```

Comment: Your tag indicates that you know a `for` loop is a good idea - would you try that? We're a [bit sensitive about prior effort](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288133/is-using-stack-overflow-for-gimme-codez-questions-encouraged) at the moment.

Comment: `for($i = 1; $i <= $leeftijd; $i++) { echo 'I must learn about <a href="http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php">for loops</a>'; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a school or application test question, anyway.. here it is:

```
if ($leeftijd > 18 && $plaats == "Eindhoven")
{ 
    for ($i = 0; $i < $leeftijd; $i++) {
         echo 'Eindhoven de gekste!';
    }
}
```

Comment: Dankjewel mvbrakel! En dat klopt, ik ben een oefentoets aan het maken voor komende vrijdag :)

Comment: Succes vrijdag dan! Dit is wel eche basics, dus volop blokken!